# React Material table how to change selection[checkboxes] position in column?

Tags: reactjs, material-table

When we create a material table and set the Selection property to true in the options. It automatically gets placed on the left most side UNLESS we add a grouping functionality then that arrow is then placed to the left most column.

Like the table below.

[image]

I wanted to make the checkboxes first in the column instead of the arrow. Basically swapping their positions in the column. Is it possible to do this in material table?

Below is my code:

```
import React, { forwardRef, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
// yarimport ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import FirstPage from '@material-ui/icons/FirstPage';
import LastPage from '@material-ui/icons/LastPage';
import Remove from '@material-ui/icons/Remove';
import SaveAlt from '@material-ui/icons/SaveAlt';
import Search from '@material-ui/icons/Search';
import ViewColumn from '@material-ui/icons/ViewColumn';
import MaterialTable from 'material-table';
import AddBox from '@material-ui/icons/AddBox';
import ArrowDownward from '@material-ui/icons/ArrowDownward';
import Check from '@material-ui/icons/Check';
import ChevronLeft from '@material-ui/icons/ChevronLeft';
import ChevronRight from '@material-ui/icons/ChevronRight';
import Clear from '@material-ui/icons/Clear';
import DeleteOutline from '@material-ui/icons/DeleteOutline';
import Edit from '@material-ui/icons/Edit';
import FilterList from '@material-ui/icons/FilterList';

const tableIcons = {
    Add: forwardRef((props, ref) => <AddBox {...props} ref={ref} />),
    Check: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Check {...props} ref={ref} />),
    Clear: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Clear {...props} ref={ref} />),
    Delete: forwardRef((props, ref) => <DeleteOutline {...props} ref={ref} />),
    DetailPanel: forwardRef((props, ref) => <ChevronRight {...props} ref={ref} />),
    Edit: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Edit {...props} ref={ref} />),
    Export: forwardRef((props, ref) => <SaveAlt {...props} ref={ref} />),
    Filter: forwardRef((props, ref) => <FilterList {...props} ref={ref} />),
    FirstPage: forwardRef((props, ref) => <FirstPage {...props} ref={ref} />),
    LastPage: forwardRef((props, ref) => <LastPage {...props} ref={ref} />),
    NextPage: forwardRef((props, ref) => <ChevronRight {...props} ref={ref} />),
    PreviousPage: forwardRef((props, ref) => <ChevronLeft {...props} ref={ref} />),
    ResetSearch: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Clear {...props} ref={ref} />),
    Search: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Search {...props} ref={ref} />),
    SortArrow: forwardRef((props, ref) => <ArrowDownward {...props} ref={ref} />),
    ThirdStateCheck: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Remove {...props} ref={ref} />),
    ViewColumn: forwardRef((props, ref) => <ViewColumn {...props} ref={ref} />)
  };
  

const TestMaterialTable = () => {

    let data = [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'a',
        surname: 'Baran',
        birthYear: 1987,
        birthCity: 63,
        sex: 'Male',
        type: 'adult'
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'b',
        surname: 'Baran',
        birthYear: 1987,
        birthCity: 34,
        sex: 'Female',
        type: 'adult',
        parentId: 1
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'c',
        surname: 'Baran',
        birthYear: 1987,
        birthCity: 34,
        sex: 'Female',
        type: 'child',
        parentId: 1
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        name: 'd',
        surname: 'Baran',
        birthYear: 1987,
        birthCity: 34,
        sex: 'Female',
        type: 'child',
        parentId: 3
      },
      {
        id: 5,
        name: 'e',
        surname: 'Baran',
        birthYear: 1987,
        birthCity: 34,
        sex: 'Female',
        type: 'child'
      },
      {
        id: 6,
        name: 'f',
        surname: 'Baran',
        birthYear: 1987,
        birthCity: 34,
        sex: 'Female',
        type: 'child',
        parentId: 5
      },
      ];


    return(
        <div>
            <MaterialTable
            icons={tableIcons}
            title="Basic Tree Data Preview"
            data={data}
            columns={[
            { title: '1', field: 'name' },
            { title: '2', field: 'surname' },
            { title: '3', field: 'sex' },
            { title: '4', field: 'type', removable: false },
            { title: '5', field: 'birthYear', type: 'numeric' },
            {
                title: '6',
                field: 'birthCity',
                lookup: { 34: 'İstanbul', 63: 'Şanlıurfa' },
            },
            ]}
            parentChildData={(row, rows) => rows.find(a => a.id === row.parentId)}
            options={{
                selection: true
            }}
        />
      </div>
    );
}

export default TestMaterialTable;
```

Comment: Seems possible by looking at [this demo](https://material-ui.com/components/tables/#collapsible-table). Can you update your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can see what your code is doing? It's difficult to help debug code if we can't see it.

Comment: I've updated it to include my code

Comment: Oh, I see. You tagged this with material-ui but the table component you are using isn't material-ui, but rather a custom wrapper around it. For the tree-data table it doesn't look like there's control over the expand toggle since it's not part of the column data.

Comment: Oh my bad, I'll remove the material-ui tagging as I thought it was still within scope.